# Jquery validation error placement outside form with absolute positing of error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, element, errorplacement

I am trying to place the error message elements outside the FORM element which is being validated. I would like to place all the error labels at the bottom of the DOM and change them to absolute position.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

                if (element.hasClass('section')){
                    element = element.parent();
                }
                offset = element.offset();
                $('#val_errors').append(error);
                error.addClass('val-message');  // add a class to the wrapper
                error.css({'position':'absolute','z-index':'10'});
                error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
                error.css('top', offset.top);

            }
```

I have checked other post which is very similar to my question, But there is no solution.
[JQ validation plugin - error labels ( errorPlacement ) outside the form, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764890/jq-validation-plugin-error-labels-errorplacement-outside-the-form-is-it-po)

Please help me out

Thanks
Venu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Venu,
This code works for me:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo($("div#errorContainer"));
}
```

Where you would already have the errorContainer already set to where you wanted it to be.  You could also set the errorContainer on the fly using normal jQuery/CSS functions:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo($("div#errorContainer"));
    $("div#errorContainer").css({'position':'absolute','z-index':'10'});
    $("div#errorContainer").css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
    $("div#errorContainer").css('top', offset.top);

}
```

It appears that you would then have to create a new div error container on the fly each time, since you are floating based on the element that threw the error, and multiple errors could be thrown.

So, the code to create new floating divs would look like:

```
 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $('body').append('<div id="error' + element.attr("id") + '" class="errorContainer"></div>');
    error.appendTo($('div#error' + element.attr("id")));
    offset = element.offset();

    $('div#error' + element.attr("id")).css({'position':'absolute','z-index':'10'});
    $('div#error' + element.attr("id")).css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
    $('div#error' + element.attr("id")).css('top', offset.top);

}
```

Then to clear messages, you could have something like:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    $('div#error' + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
})
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the reply. But I would like to position error element, but not the error container. I want to keep those all error elements away from the from.

Comment: Venu,  The div with ID errorContainer can be absolutely anywhere you'd like.  It has nothing to do with the form, it's just a container.  So, you could have, anywhere on the page <div id="errorContainer" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;z-index:10"></div>

Comment: Right Brian, But I want to position each element absolutely not the container.

Comment: When I added absolutely positioned elements to container, error elements appear OK if you enter some invalid data into the input, BUT after you enter valid data, the labels don't get removed. (i guess since the error label is not a child of the form element, the validation plugin simply doesn't find it)

Comment: Venu, add this line before error.appendTo:          $('body').append('<div id="error' + element.attr("id") + '"></div>');
Then, replace "div#errorContainer" with 'div#error' + element.attr("id")

Comment: Hmm i tried but not working. Is it different from my actual code in the question?

Comment: $('body').append('<div id="error' + element.attr("id") + '"></div>');    error.appendTo($('div#error' + element.attr("id")));     offset = element.offset();
$('div#error' + element.attr("id")).css({'position':'absolute','z-index':'10'});     $('div#error' + element.attr("id")).css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());     $('div#error' + element.attr("id")).css('top', offset.top);

Comment: Yeah Brian, your updated answer is working. I found small issue with it.. It is adding many error elements, I fixed it by adding below condition...
if(!$('div#error' + element.attr("id")).length){
    $('body').append('<div id="error' + element.attr("id") + '" class="errorContainer"></div>');
}

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so instead of using the `errorPlacement` function which can only be used inside a form, i used the `errorLabelContainer` setting with a `div` outside my form :

```
$("#my-form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer : "#div_outside_form"
});
```

Now I can put my message anywhere I want with css, but unfortunately, unlike `errorPlacement`, I cannot customize each one of them.
So i went into the `jquery.validate.js` and looked for the place where the error label are positionned : it's line 652 in the version 1.9.0

```
if ( !this.labelContainer.append(label).length )
    this.settings.errorPlacement
       ? this.settings.errorPlacement(label, $(element) )
       : label.insertAfter(element);
```

I replaced those lines by

```
if ( this.labelContainer.append(label).length ){
    if (typeof(this.settings.labelCustomize)!='undefined')
        this.settings.labelCustomize(label,$(element));
}else{
        this.settings.errorPlacement
       ? this.settings.errorPlacement(label, $(element) )
       : label.insertAfter(element);
}
```

to add a hook on the settings called `labelCustomize`. The only thing left is to define this function in the validate call :

```
$("#my-form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer : "#div_outside_form",
    labelCustomize : function(error, element) {
      var offset = element.offset();
      error.css("position","absolute")
         .css("top",offset.top)
         .css("left",offset.left-element.outerWidth());
    }
});
```

I just tried it so I'm not confident about the reliability of this method, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer here was provided by @dendscie, but it required changing the jQuery Validate source code.  There's a way to do it without that, by taking the `defaultShowErrors` function in jQuery Validate and slightly modifying it in your `showErrors` option:

```
$('#my-form').validate({
    errorLabelContainer:'#div_outside_of_form',
    errorPlacement: function(error,element){
        //put the error absolutely positioned beside the element but
        //"floating" over any overflow:hidden divs/forms
        error.position({
            my: 'left center',
            at: 'right center',
            of: element,
            offset: '5 0'
        });
    },
    showErrors: function() {
        for ( var i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++ ) {
            var error = this.errorList[i];
            this.settings.highlight && this.settings.highlight.call( this, error.element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
            this.showLabel( error.element, error.message );
            //This is the only line different than the defaultShowErrors the code is taken from
            this.settings.errorPlacement(this.errorsFor(error.element), $(error.element) );
        }
        if( this.errorList.length ) {
            this.toShow = this.toShow.add( this.containers );
        }
        if (this.settings.success) {
            for ( var i = 0; this.successList[i]; i++ ) {
                this.showLabel( this.successList[i] );
            }
        }
        if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
            for ( var i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                this.settings.unhighlight.call( this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
            }
        }
        this.toHide = this.toHide.not( this.toShow );
        this.hideErrors();
        this.addWrapper( this.toShow ).show();
    });
```

Combine with some CSS that makes your error labels absolutely positioned:

```
                label.error {
                    background-color:white;
                    color:red;
                    position:absolute;
                    border: 1px black solid;
                    padding: 10px;
                    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888;
                    z-index:1;
                }
```